# How do I download code from this github site

Tags: github

I want to download this example c# project...

https://github.com/Code-Inside/Samples/tree/master/2013/RazorWebApiOwin

I cant figure out how to get it. Do I need to learn how to use git to get it or is there an easier way?

Comment: You wrote "gitlab" in the title. Is that a typo for "github"?

Comment: @keith thompson - yes, fixed, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Click on the <> code tab on the Right hand side.
2. Click the Download ZIP button